# Laravel Change database column when button is clicked

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to change the status of a task to complete. I have a status_id column in the database and 1 equals complete. I would like the click of the button to change the status_id to 1

My route

```
Route::patch('/tasks/completed/{Task}', 'TasksController@completedUpdate')->name('completedUpdate');
```

My button

```
<form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    <button type="submit" class="button is-inverted" style="margin-top: 10px;">Mark Complete</button>
  </form>
```

My controller

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, $task)
{
    $task->status_id = $request->status_id;

    $task->save;

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'task marked complete');
}
```

the error it gives me is:

> Attempt to assign property of non-object

Let me know if any more info is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, $task)
{
    $task->status_id = $request->status_id;

    $task->save;

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'task marked complete');
}
```

into:

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $task->status_id = $request->status_id;

    $task->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'task marked complete');
}
```

so you need to typehint type of $task variable and use `save()` method instead of `save` property.

Also probably instead of:

```
/tasks/completed/{Task}
```

you should use:

```
/tasks/completed/{task}
```

Comment: ok thank you! how does the controller know to change the status_id to 1

Comment: This is done in this line `$task->status_id = $request->status_id;` - you send 1 in `$request->status_id` so it's set to 1 and in next line it's saved

Answer (score 1):

`$task->save;` should be `$task->save();`

With `->save`, it is looking for a property on the model, hence the error message re 'assigning a property'.  Whereas `->save()` calls the save method on the object.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember that about save

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you're assigning the `$task->status_id` a value of `$request->status_id` but you're actually not passing the status_id in your form in your HTML code. You can put a hidden element in your form which is `<input name="status_id" value="1" />`.

In the meanwhile, do not forget that `$task->save;` must be `$task->save();`

Good luck!

Comment: ok thank you! I have added that input to the form and hid it but do I need to add anything to the controller?

Comment: @L.Fox No you won't. You just need to explicit it somewhere in your controller that you want to set the column to 1, you can hard-code it or use a hidden input in the submitted form.